# Omit first parameter of a multiparameter currying function

Tags: scala, function, parameter-passing

Is there a way to avoid the first comb function parameter?

```
def sum(comb: (Int, Int) => Int)(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  if(a >= b) b
  else comb(f(a), sum(comb)(f)(a + 1, b))
}
val func = sum(x => x)(1, 5)
```

For example, could I declare something like this so that I could define my combining function later in the code, or is it mandatory that I change the order of the parameters list?

Comment: `sum(_: (Int, Int) => Int)(x => x)(1, 5)`, type inference doesn't work here

Comment: `val f: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int = sum(_)(x => x)(1, 5)`

Comment: So both your answers are fitting. So, would you post them properly so that I can pick one as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, either:

```
val f: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int = sum(_)(x => x)(1, 5)
```

or

```
sum(_: (Int, Int) => Int)(x => x)(1, 5)
```